# limit point of the set of integers

Tags: general-topology

What are the limit point of the set of integers? I know that the closure of this set is the set of integers, so is this set of limit points empty?

Comment: The closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is **not** $\mathbb{R}$, at least not in the standard topology.

Comment: What topology are you working in?

Comment: My mistake. I meant to say the closure is $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: You can edit your question to correct your mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The confusion here is that the definition of a limit point $x$ in a set $X$ requires that every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $X$ *different from* $x$. A limit point is also known as an *accumulation point*.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point

This is in contrast to the definition of an *adherent point*, also known as a *contact point*, which is a point whose every neighborhood intersects $X$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adherent_point

If a set is closed, then every one of its points are adherent points; but not necessarily limit points. For example the set $[0, 1] \cup \{2\}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$. Every point is an adherent point, but $2$ is not a limit point.

This terminology a common point of confusion.

To answer the original question, the integers have no limit points in the reals, since all integers are *isolated*; that is, each integer has a neighborhood that does not contain any other integers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume your space is $\Bbb{R}$ with the standard topology. You claimed that $\overline{\Bbb{Z}} = \Bbb{Z}$ (which is correct, assuming you are indeed using the standard topology.) Since $\overline{\Bbb{Z}} = \Bbb{Z}$ we know $\Bbb{Z}$ is closed with respect to $\Bbb{R}$. Hence **if** $\space \Bbb{Z}$ has a limit point, say $p$, then $p \in \Bbb{Z}$. However, for all $p \in \Bbb{Z}$, you can take the open set $\left(p-\frac{1}{2},p+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and use the definition of a limit point $$\Bbb{Z}\cap \left[\left(p-\frac{1}{2},p+\frac{1}{2}\right) - \{p\} \right] =\emptyset$$ to see that $\Bbb{Z}$ contains no limit points.

Comment: Doesn't the sequence $2, 2, 2, \ldots$ converge to $2 \in \mathbb Z$? Doesn't that make $2$ a limit point in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: that's what is confusing me actually

Comment: @JohnHughes  See my answer. 2 is an adherent point but not a limit point.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification...my mistake!